# Сильная нагрузка Visual Studio 2019 на мой процессор

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

Столкнулся с проблемой.

Во время роботы Visual Studio 2019 на моем ПК, происходить сильная нагрузка на мой процессор.

Вот нагрузка на мой процессор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть причина сильной нагрузки на мой процессор.

Спасибо за внимания.

Comment: В вижле конечно. А вы как думали? Если хотите меньший расход ресурсов, то выбирайте что-то менее ресурсоемкое

Comment: @aepot Добавил вверху список процессов VS.

Comment: Если проект хелло-ворлд, то нагрузка конечно огромная. Может процессор-память маленькие-слабенькие?

Comment: У меня Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500 CPU @ 3.00GHz

Comment: IntelliSense? Или как он там... Тот что код анализирует и потом авто подсказки делает. [В простое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYKHh.png) `Intel Core i3 3.99 GHz`.

Comment: Кстати, плагины стоят какие-то?

Comment: Если там проект на плюсах с огромным деревом зависимостей, то картина понятна, хотя у меня даже Qt на пеньке такую нагрузку не держал.